# For how many years, aggregate, were the requiremenst of the Law actually carried out?

Tags: torah-service

I am certainly no expert on Hebrew history so pls be patient with me :). I do read a bit and have not been able to put together an answer on my own - maybe because there are too many nuances, and too little detailed history. From the Law given to and through Moses, unto the destruction of 2nd temple by the Romans appears to be a span  of about 1600 years, depending on whose calcs one chooses. Sadly during much of that span the provisions and demands of sacrifice, tithes, penal enforcement etc weren't carried  out. Putting together the periods when the faithful held sway and the requirements of the Law were well-kept, enforced, implemented - how many years was that? Or for what portion %-age of that history were the people 'faithful' in their obligations?

Links would be fine... I have tried searching but it is unwieldy. Timelines [which I prefer  when well-done] really don't detail what is necessary to try to educated-guess it.

thank you!!

Comment: Hi Richard, I think you will find that in every generation there are faithful and not so faithful people according to their level and actions.

Comment: Thx, but not germane to the question. This isn’t about “the remnant” but the national observance of all requirements of the Law. It is written that such was the case during the reign of Josiah once he understood the Law as found written in that day. But between the early part of Solomon’s rule and Josiah was there any period during which all provisions were observed including many laws requiring punishment of offenses? The foregoing is just one example